# How to have GoogleNews Package return a list of news articles about a list of stocks

Tags: python, stock

Right now, I have created a program that fetched news articles about a stock using the GoogleNews package.

```
import datetime as dt

from GoogleNews import GoogleNews
from newspaper import Article
from newspaper import Config

now = dt.date.today()
now = now.strftime('%m-%d-%Y')
yesterday = dt.date.today() - dt.timedelta(days = 1)
yesterday = yesterday.strftime('%m-%d-%Y')

now = dt.date.today()
now = now.strftime('%m-%d-%Y')
yesterday = dt.date.today() - dt.timedelta(days = 1)
yesterday = yesterday.strftime('%m-%d-%Y')

googlenews = GoogleNews(start=yesterday, end=now)
googlenews.search("AMZN")
result = googlenews.result()
print(result)
```

I would like to have GoogleNews return me a list of news articles about a list of stocks.

```
stocks = [‘AAPL’, ‘AMZN’, ‘GOOGL’]
```

This would be my list of stocks, and I would like to have it return me a list of news articles based off these stock symbols. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: This is not a programming question, this is more of a question for Google support. You need to find out if GoogleNews really supports this feature.

Comment: @Shameel I’m not using the official Google news api. I’m using a Google news package from Python. https://pypi.org/project/GoogleNews/ I was wondering if there was a way to make the GoogleNews.search() function search for articles about multiple topics.

Comment: The page has usage examples and it looks like it supports search based on keywords and not stock symbols. You should probably set up a dictionary/map of Stock symbols with common keywords associated with them and do the search.

Comment: It also works on stock symbols. Basically, I have a website where I want to display articles based on what stocks the user has picked previously. I can pull articles about 1 stock symbol. I just want to know if there is a way to get articles about multiple stock symbols.

Comment: Put the symbols in an array and loop through them.

Comment: I was thinking about that, but the problem would then be that if a user has a lot of stocks picked out, then looping through the array in such volume would take a lot of time because I would have to call the package every time

Comment: Prefetch commonly picked out stocks and store them in a cache, and fetch it from cache when needed.

Comment: @Shameel Do you think it would be better to have it display what stocks the user has picked or do you think it would be okay if I just display news about the stock market in their location? I would also have a search bar where the user can search for articles about specific stocks.